# extract the data out from a large list

Tags: javascript, math

I have a list like bellow:

```
var list = [
  {
    id:1,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 1, 
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 1,
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 2,
  },
  {
    id:4,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 2,
  },
  {
    id:6,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 2,
  },

  {
    id:8,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 5,
  },

  {
    id:9,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 8,
  },
  ...
]
```

you see the list, the item in the list has a `type_a` param:

I want to extract `type_a` out, and aggregation the same type_a to be like this:

```
{
  8: [  // the 8 is `type_a`
    {
        id:9,
        name: 'bss',
        type_a: 8,
      },
    ], 
  },
  5: [
    {
        id:8,
        name: 'bss',
        type_a: 5,
      },
  ] 
  ...
}
```

Whether there is a more efficient function to achieve this?

I can use two for-loop to achieve this, first is gather type_a types, and the other for the list, if equals to the `type_a` item.

Comment: More efficient than what? Why is this tagged [tag:math]? What have you actually tried and what is your specific question?

Comment: I use two for-loop . see my edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` for that output:

```js
var list = [
  {
    id:1,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 1, 
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 1,
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 2,
  },
  {
    id:4,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 2,
  },
  {
    id:6,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 2,
  },

  {
    id:8,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 5,
  },

  {
    id:9,
    name: 'bss',
    type_a: 8,
  }
];

var res = list.reduce((acc, item)=>{
  if(acc[item.type_a]){
    acc[item.type_a].push(item);
    return acc;
  }
  acc[item.type_a] = [];
  acc[item.type_a].push(item);
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```